# Jenkins job to deploy a generated jar into a Unix SSH server

Tags: git, maven, unix, jenkins, ssh

I am trying to create a Jenkins job that deploys my maven project jar into a Unix SSH server. I have created the jenkins job that will fetch the code from the git repository and do a maven install and created the jar file in my root workspace. Now I want that generated jar to be deployed in to a UNIX SSH server. Could any one please provide me some insights for the same. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the job in the `master`, you can install a `slave` in the UNIX SSH Server and run your job on that particular slave where it will build the `JAR file` and then deploy it where ever you want in the UNIX server.

Answer (score 0):

At the simplest level, you can run a shell command to copy the file to the remote server.

```
$ scp my-file user@remote-host:/some/dir
```

Alternatively, you can use tools like chef/ansible/puppet to automate different deployment tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `Publish Over SSH Plugin` to transfer your files in Workspace to remote SSH machine using this plugin.

Comment: Hi ,I have added Publish Over SSH Plugin in Jenkins and chosen Send build artifacts over SSH in Post build actions by giving exec command as pscp -i ./wso2-dev-build-private.ppk ./workspace/TestmavenProject/workflow/target/*.jar user@<hostname>:/apim/files/repo/comp/dropins.
But it is giving below error during the build

SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [pscp -i ./wso2-dev-build-private.ppk ./workspace/TestmavenProject/workflow/target/*.jar user@<hostname>:/apim/files/repo/comp/dropins]
SSH: EXEC: connected
bash: pscp: command not found. 
Is any plugin required for executing pscp?

Answer (score 0):

You can scp the jar file to target location - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SCP+plugin